# Bizarre String.Index error in Xcode 7.0beta5: 'advancedBy' method not available

Tags: xcode, string, swift, swift2, xcode7

Going in circles trying to figure out why the first line below won't compile. This is just a playground but it doesn't matter if it's part of an App, same problem. Xcode 7beta5 / Swift.

Error is: `'Index' does not have a member named 'advancedBy'`

```
"Why doesn't this work".startIndex.advancedBy(3) // Won't compile

"This does work".startIndex.successor() // Works
"So does this".endIndex.predecessor() // Works
```

Comment: Just update Xcode to the latest App Store version (7.1) https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

Comment: It would seem to be such a serious problem that I thought it would never happen in a public beta, and instead there might be something wrong with my configuration. Otherwise there would be bug report or discussion, but I could not find anything.

Comment: try "defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode"  on terminal

Comment: Well you're right about updating...oh well.